# Advantage Error 6082

Tags: c#, .net, advantage-database-server

I'm creating a windows service. This service has to read data from an Advantage Database once a day.

I copied the Advantage database on my computer and it works fine but when I try the service on the server I have the following error :

> "AdsException : Error 6082:  Error loading the Advantage Local Server library."

According to the doc ([link](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?error_6082_error_loading_the_advantage_local_server_dll.htm)) I have to put the ADSLOC32.DLL in \WINDOWS\SYSTEM directory.

I try that but it does not work.

Any ideas?

EDIT : I created a console application that executes exactly the same code as my windows service, and it works exactly as it should. It seems that the problem is from my service, but I don't know what part of my service is wrong...

EDIT 2 : I checked with the process monitor and my service doesn't try to load adsloc32.dll, it tries to load adsloc64.dll. I did not found an adsloc64.dll file so I make a copy of adsloc32.dll to my application directory and named it adsloc64.dll but it didn't work.

Comment: You should always use System32 (32-Bit system) or SysWOW64 (on a 64-bit system) for 32-Bit DLLs instead of System (which is the old 16-Bit Windows directory). The documentation is not correct in that regard. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Well Windows still searches the 16-Bit directory, but only for backwards compatibility. See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There already is a adsloc32.dll file in both System32 and SysWow64.
I try to put that file into my application directory but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

I used Process Monitor from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) to know from where the program tries to load the dll files.
And it wasn't trying to load adsloc32.dll, it was loading adsloc64.dll.

I just put the adsloc64.dll file to my application directory and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting adsloc32.dll to the same directory as your application. Maybe there are some problems with rights